# MSVC - C2668 ambiguous call to overloaded function - Is it a compiler bug?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, cl

MSVC 19.28 rejects the following code with the error message: C2668 ambiguous call to overloaded function `A::Foo`.
Is it a compiler bug? It compiles fine with gcc, clang and even msvc 19.10.
It fails since MSVC 19.14, see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/qq7j68)

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void Foo(int = {}) {
        std::cout << "Hello World";
    }

    template<typename... T, typename... Args>
    void Foo(Args&&... args) {

    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.Foo<int>();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the call `Foo<int>()` the compiler can deduce `Foo<int>()` for the first template, and `Foo<int>(void)` for the second.

From [temp.deduct.partial#11](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.partial#11):

> ... if G has a trailing function parameter pack for which F does not have a corresponding parameter, and if F does not have a trailing function parameter pack, then F is more specialized than G.

This is a tie breaker, and the first template is selected.

Not being able to resolve the ambiguity appears to be a MSVC bug.

Comment: "for which F does not have a corresponding parameter" - but F does have a corresponding parameter, the anonymous `int` parameter?